# How to update document in Mongo without loosing data in a Spring Mongotemplate project

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am new to Spring and MongoDB. I am trying to update a document, but every time I update some fields, the others disappear.

This is my current method:

```
    public UpdateResult updateCentro(String id, JsonNode jsonNode) {
        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
        Update update = Update.fromDocument(JsonNodeToDocumentConverter.INSTANCE.convert(jsonNode));
        return mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "centros");
    }
```

If the object that I give to the update method has 3 fields to be updated, in the database it leaves me those 3, but it deletes all the others.

I am trying to do something like this, but using mongoTemplate in Spring:

```
db.foo.update({"_id" :ObjectId("4e93037bbf6f1dd3a0a9541a") },{$set : {"key1":"value1",""key2":"value2",....}})
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior when you use the `Update.fromDocument()` method. From the API Docs: _"Creates an Update instance from the given Document. Allows to explicitly exclude fields from making it into the created Update object. Note, that this will set attributes directly and not use $set. This means fields not given in the Document will be nulled when executing the update. To create an only-updating Update instance of a Document, call set(String, Object) for each value in it."_

Comment: The thing is that to make the application flexible and generic, I have not created any Java entity to map. I directly use the JsonNode. That allows me to save any structure that comes to me in mongoDB. The problem is that I do not have any class to do "set". There is no method to update only the fields that I pass without deleting the other fields and without having to do "set" for each one of them?

Answer (score 3):

> If the object that I give to the update method has 3 fields to be
> updated, in the database it leaves me those 3, but it deletes all the
> others.

As I have mentioned in the *comments* above, that is the expected behavior of the `Update.fromDocument()` method:

> Note, that this will set attributes directly and not use $set. This
> means fields not given in the Document will be nulled when executing
> the update.

So, use this to update the specific fields:

```
Query query = ...;
Update update = new Update().set("key-1", "value 1").set("key-2", "value 2");
UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Document.class, "collection_name");
```

Note the `Document` is of type `org.bson.Document`.

Comment: Yes, I had already understood your answer. The problem is that I have a JsonNode that contains many keys / value and even arrays and objects nested at different levels in that jsonNode. I can't think of how to convert all that hierarchy of levels to a key: value list to use in sets.

Comment: You can include a sample document you are trying to update, and also a sample of the update document - in your question. The process you had used summarily replaced the document (you know that already). One way is to create an entity/POJO mapped to yur collection document. Another option is to somehow (I don't know how, and is beyond the scope) build the `Update#set` using the key-value information from the `JsonNode` (JsonNode has keys values and has API to extract them).

Answer (score 0):

Using some prasad's information, this is my solution:

```
    
    public UpdateResult updateCentro(String id, JsonNode jsonNode) {
        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
        Update update = new Update();

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = jsonNode.fields();
        while (fields.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
            String key = field.getKey();
            JsonNode value = field.getValue();
            JsonNodeType type = value.getNodeType();
            switch (type) {
            case ARRAY:
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(value);
                List<JsonNode> list = new ArrayList<JsonNode>();
                for (JsonNode arrayItem : value) {
                    list.add(arrayItem);
                }
                update.set(key, list);
                break;
            case BINARY:

                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                update.set(key, value.asBoolean());
                break;
            case MISSING:

                break;
            case NULL:

                break;
            case NUMBER:
                update.set(key, value.asDouble());
                break;
            case OBJECT:
                update.set(key, value);
                break;
            case POJO:

                break;
            case STRING:
                update.set(key, value.asText());
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "centros");
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Vikitor - i tried to follow this- because i have a similar requirement.. can i ask a question to you ?